# Hit count breakpoints are not showing current count properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using C++ Visual Studio 2010.

When I set a *Hit Count* breakpoints of let say 100, it will break after 100 iterations but it will always report the actual count as 0 which make the use of hit count pretty useless.

Does anyone know how to make the *Hit Count* breakpoints work again?
This problem only affect my main solution of 33 projects.

Comment: You say "again", is there a time when they worked correctly?  Do they work correctly if you start a new project?

Comment: Yes it works ok in a new solution. It only affect my main solution